# ListView inside ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, onitemclicklistener

I am writing an application where using `ListView` inside `ViewPager`. Here I need to get `onItemClick` for list item click but it's not working.

Any suggestion here, is there anything we need to maintain while using `ListView` inside `ViewPager`?

Comment: you can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189316/listfragments-inside-viewpager

Comment: Thanks...but it will not work in my case...Since I have some other component along side ListView to use.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewPager, you must be using fragments. In any of those fragments, you can register onItemClick event for a listview.

Comment: yes that is obvious choice to implement ViewPager with FragmentAdapter in this case. But some how itemClickListener not working.

Comment: post your code where you have registered that event

Comment: dear...it;s same like generally we do : lstView.setOnItemClickListener(context); inside Fragment(View pager child).

Comment: check if context is correct. it should be OnItemClickListener interface.

Comment: yes it is there and since then only I could able to check at runtime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66461/discussion-between-shubh-and-techhelper).

Comment: try this:yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int arg2, long arg3) {
       onClick(arg2);
      }
     });